# Using Awk to replace strings in one file with strings from other file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a tab deliminated, File A, like this

```
establishment_of_protein_localization_to_endoplasmic_reticulum  GO:0072599
    lipid_oxidation GO:0034440
    endocytic_vesicle_lumen GO:0071682
    monocarboxylic_acid_metabolic_process   GO:0032787
    protein_transmembrane_transport GO:0071806
    cellular_response_to_topologically_incorrect_protein    GO:0035967
    preribosome GO:0030684
    negative_regulation_of_hematopoietic_progenitor_cell_differentiation    GO:1901533
```

and a second file structure as such:

```
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 10.86px;
font-weight: 700;
text-anchor: middle;
fill: #000000;
stroke: none;">
GO:0072599
</text>

<text x="509.10" y="-243.88"

style="
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 10.72px;
font-weight: 700;
text-anchor: middle;
fill: #000000;
stroke: none;">
GO:0034440
</text>
```

and i want to use awk or sed to match the **second** column of file a to the second file and replace the matching strings with the first column of file in the second file and replace them with the first column. To give this ouput essentially

```
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 10.86px;
font-weight: 700;
text-anchor: middle;
fill: #000000;
stroke: none;">
 establishment_of_protein_localization_to_endoplasmic_reticulum 
</text>

<text x="509.10" y="-243.88"

style="
font-family: Helvetica;
font-size: 10.72px;
font-weight: 700;
text-anchor: middle;
fill: #000000;
stroke: none;">
lipid_oxidation
</text>
```

Except the `GO:######` Sequences match the column in the first file. I tried using this command

```
#!/bin/bash

    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{$1=a[$1\2];}1' input.csv
```

however, it replaces more than just the strings in column 2 of file a

Comment: the output is wrong: `regulation_of_muscle_system_process GO:0090257` does not relate to `GO:0045927`. Update your description

Comment: Yeah could give us proper input and output so that we can help you?

Comment: Hi Allan, I just corrected the input and the output to match. I apologize, it was suppose to be symbolic but it should now make more sense

Comment: @Rnewbie, elaborate whether those asterisks `**est...` really  appear in your file

Comment: Whoops, that was my attempt to make the change my clear, they do not - i have fixed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are looking forward to is something like below. But your output does not match your input file

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ hashKey[$2]=$1; next }$1 in hashKey{$1=hashKey[$1]}1' FS='\t' file1 file2
```

The idea is we hash the values in the second column of the first file which is tab-separated. Then on the second values for those values in first column which are present in the hash table, we update the value from the stored hash.